# Why isn't my Caesar's encryption problem not running?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm having problems with running this loop for an assignment for university. It runs the first one giving the first letter correct, but then giving an error because the endindex is out of range somehow. I've tried adjusting multiple things, but it still doesn't work.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at Assignment4.Question4.main(Question4.java:18)
```

My code:

```
package Assignment4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question4 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type a string: ");
    String message = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Type a key of the same length: ");
    String key = in.nextLine();
    in.close();

    int messageLength = message.length();

    for (int a = 0, b = 1; a < messageLength && b <= messageLength; a++, b++) {
      key = key.substring(a,b);
      message = message.substring(a,b);
      System.out.print(String.valueOf((char)(message.charAt(0) + Integer.parseInt(key))));
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the variable `key` in your loop.

```java
for (int a = 0, b = 1; a < messageLength && b <= messageLength; a++, b++) {
      key = key.substring(a,b);
```

The first iteration gives you the very first character of the initial value for `key` and "overrides" `key` by this character. The next iteration with `a == 1` and `b == 2` will cause a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `key` has only the length 1.

---

*FYI:* The same error will be caused by `message`.

---

To solve the problem you'll need additional variables to store the temporary results and the final result.